# How to randomly generate weak orderings of a given length in a uniform fashion?

Tags: random, order-theory

I recently found out how to calculate [the number of all possible weak orderings of a given length](https://oeis.org/A000670). Now, however, I am looking for a way not to only count but to also randomly generate these orderings with a uniform distribution. For, example, for sequences of length 3, there are 13 possible orderings:

```
1 2 3
3 2 1
1 3 2
2 1 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
1 1 3
1 3 1
3 1 1
3 3 1
3 1 3
1 3 3
1 1 1
```

Is there a method to uniformly generate such orderings at random?

Comment: What about 1 2 2 and permutations?

Comment: but not `1 3 3` and permutations

Comment: @Aryabhata From the point of view of ordering, `1 2 2` and `1 3 3` are the same. You have one value lesser than the other two that are equal.

Comment: @MarcinZalewski: Yeah, was just looking to clarify what you exactly wanted...

Comment: @ Aryabhata: OK, yeah, I was looking for just weak order permutations. Turns out that my question is answered very well in a paper I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime, I found the answer to my question in a paper listed on the [Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A000670). The paper:

> "[Generating random weak orders and the probability of a Condorcet winner](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41106878)" by Hans Maassen and Thom Bezembinder.

Basically, the procedure goes as follows (copied from the paper):

> *Let $A$ be a set of $m$ elements, $m \geq 1$. Let a stochastic weak order $R$
> on $A$ be generated by the following algorithm:*

1. *Draw an integer-valued random variable $K$ according to the probability distribution $\pi_m$. (See the instruction below).*
2. *To each $a \in A$ assign a random score $X_a$ according to the uniform distribution on $\lbrace 1; \ldots ;K \rbrace$.*
3. *Put $aRb$ iff $X_a \leq X_b$.*

To generate numbers according to distribution $\pi_m$, do the following:

> 

1. *Choose a small number $\delta$ such that $1/\delta$ is of the order of the total number of weak orders to be generated ($W_m$, can be calculated using the formula in the paper), and find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so large that*
   $$
   W_m - \sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{k^m}{2^{k+1}}<\delta.
   $$
2. *Fill an array with the partial sums $S_0, S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_N$* given by:
   $$
   S_k := \sum_{j=0}^k\frac{j^m}{2^{j+1}}, k = 0, 1, \ldots, N-1;\quad S_N := W_m.
   $$
3. *For each of the weak orders to be sampled:*

   1. *Let $Y := W_m \cdot RND(1)$, where $RND(1)$ produces a random number uniformly over $[0, 1]$.*
   2. Let $K$ be the least integer for which $S_K \geq Y$.

The details of why this works are in the paper.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy enough as a programming exercise, for example in R:

First generate the weak orders in ascending order

```
n <- 3
orderwo <- matrix(1)
for (i in 2:n){orderwo <- rbind(cbind(orderwo,orderwo[,i-1]),cbind(orderwo,i))}
```

which produces something like

```
> orderwo 
       i  
[1,] 1 1 1
[2,] 1 2 2
[3,] 1 1 3
[4,] 1 2 3
```

then permute these but only keep unique patterns

```
p <- t(perms(n))
permwo <- unique(matrix(orderwo[1,p], ncol=n))
for (i in 2:2^(n-1)){permwo <- rbind(permwo, unique(matrix(orderwo[i,p], ncol=n)))}
```

which produces something like

```
> permwo 
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    2    2
 [3,]    2    1    2
 [4,]    2    2    1
 [5,]    1    1    3
 [6,]    1    3    1
 [7,]    3    1    1
 [8,]    1    2    3
 [9,]    1    3    2
[10,]    2    1    3
[11,]    2    3    1
[12,]    3    1    2
[13,]    3    2    1
```

then sample uniformly from this list

```
permwo[sample(nrow(permwo), 4, replace = TRUE), ]
```

which produces something like

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    2    1
[2,]    1    1    3
[3,]    1    2    3
[4,]    3    1    2
```

Comment: Henry, thanks. In the meantime, I found this paper:

"Generating random weak orders and the probability of a Condorcet winner" by Hans Maassen and Thom Bezembinder.

It pretty much answers my question. Your answer is something that one would consider, but [unfortunately it could be infeasible](https://oeis.org/A000670) for any sequences that are reasonably long.